# Can connect mysql database via navicate but cant from c# application

Tags: c#, mysql

here is all info.
Step 1

[image: Navicate Connection Success Method]

Step 2- Error Msg
[image]

Step 3- connection String
[image]

I have tried without using port number but the problem is same. There is IP restrictions for remote login. but if it is because of IP restriction why am I able to connect with Navicat.

Code of C# where i'm getting error.[image]

Comment: Show the code that uses the connectionstring

Comment: I have shown the code now. in query i'm passing "Select NOW()"

Comment: Your connection string is "Server-198..." ? Try to set server= and make Replacement - on  = in your connection string,

Comment: @lis  It is not -. it is =. because of image size it shows - instead of =.

Comment: Just insert your params: "server=;port=;User Id=;password=;Persist Security Info=True;database=;CharSet=utf8;"

Comment: Thank you @Lis but problem is the same. after adding these parameters still the problem is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per step 1 it seems the connection has been successfully established, but still you are unable to connect to the specific database. Check the name of the database or confirm that the database exists with the name supplied in the connection string. You can do that even by creating a connection from Navicat. If the database exists you will find it there.

Cheers

Comment: It worked like a charm. the database which i tried to connect is not exists with these credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should invoke `mysqlcon.Open()` before using `mysqlcon`.

Comment: Read about the behavior of dataadapters when the connection is closed

Comment: @Steve Have you give permission to the user to access the database `act*`?